# Regex for extracting S'#'E'#'

Tags: javascript, regex

We have a bunch of files that are named like, `'My.File.S01E01.something.something'` or `'My.File.S01E02.another.something'` or `'My_File.S1E1.something'`.

What I'm trying to do is extract the text before the `S01E01` or `S1E1` (so for example, the above would return `My.File.` or `My_File.` and also extract the values for S and E, being `S01 (S = 01)` or `S1 (S = 1)` etc.

Would anyone know how I can do this? or point me in the right direction, I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match all the text before `S##` and not worry about matching specifically `S##E##`. The key is to check make sure there is no number or letter before the `S`. For example you would want to ignore `filenames02` as being invalid.

Also, some torrents contain spam at the front of the name. Such as `[torrent.com]My.File.S01E01.zip` you can skip that as well (if you want).

The regex to match just the filename is `/^(\[.+\])?(.+[^a-z0-9])(?=S\d)/i`. If you want to include the spam, then `/^(.+[^a-z0-9])(?=S\d)/i` is all you need.

```
var names = [
    "My.File.S1E1.something",
    "My File S01E01.something",
    "[--spam--] My.File.S01E01.something",
    "My.Files S01 something",

    // these won't match
    "My.FilesS01E01.something"
];
for(var i=0; i < names.length; i++)
{
    var name = names[i];
    name = name.match(/^(\[.+\])?(.+[^a-z0-9])(?=S\d)/i);
    $('body').append('<div>'+name[2]+'</div>');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingmedia/fZDM4/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var file = 'My.File.S01E02.something.something';
var S = file.match(/(?:\.S)([0-9]+)(?:E[0-9]+\.)/)[1];
var E = file.match(/(?:\.S[0-9]+E)([0-9]+)(?:\.)/)[1];
```

Next:

```
S === "01"
E === "02"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an algorithm than a simple regex.
http://jsfiddle.net/GqJPU/

```
var file1 = 'My.File.S01E01.something.something';
var file2 = 'My.File.S01E02.another.something';
var file3 = 'My_File.S1E1.something';

var myFiles = [file1, file2, file3];

myFiles.forEach(function(e, i){
      var myReturn = returnFileDefs(e);
      console.log(myReturn);
});

function returnFileDefs(element){
    var myResult = {};
    var mySplit = element.split('\.');
    var front = mySplit[0];
    var re = /_/g;      

    if(re.test(front)){
        myResult.front = front;
        myResult.middle = mySplit[1];
    }else{
        myResult.front = mySplit[0]+'.'+mySplit[1];
        myResult.middle = mySplit[2];
    }
    myResult.S = myResult.middle.match(/(S)([0-9]+)/)[2];
    myResult.E = myResult.middle.match(/(E)([0-9]+)/)[2];
    return myResult;
}
```