# Java Extract substring

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I have several files like,

> "reportD05S01.xml", "2018.annualD01S02.pdf",
>   "2018.05.monthlyD01S03.pdf", etc...

How can I extract only the first parts of each file, let's say in "**reportD05S01.xml**", I only want to get "**report**" and in "**2018.annualD01S02.pdf**", only the "**2018.annual**" and so on. So basically, *D[some_numbers]S[some_numbers].[extension] are being ditched*.

These files are located in a directory and I'm getting the list using the following code:

```
File dir = new File("/home/buddika/Inventory_Sales/Reports/");
File[] content = dir.listFiles();
```

and iterate through the "content" array using a for loop.
I attempted the following approach available in this link for javascript [see post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333250/regex-for-extracting-se) but with no luck.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/^(\\[.+\\])?(.+[^a-z0-9])(?=D\\d)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
```

How can I make it possible using Java?
Any help would be appreciated.

My current code looks like

```
File dir = new File("/home/buddika/Inventory_Sales/Reports/");
File[] content = dir.listFiles();

   for(int i=0; i<content.length; i++){
    String name = content[i].getName();

    // extracting everything before department and section
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)D\\d+S\\d+\\.[^.]*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);

    if(matcher.matches()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }           
   }
```

Comment: Do not use regex delimiters in Java regexps. Case insensitivity is set using `(?i)` in the pattern or with `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` option (what you are already doing).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, that was quite useful! I will modify the code.

Comment: You still have a `/` before `^`. Please share a part of the `content`.

Comment: Try `"(.*?)D\\d+S\\d+\\.[^.]*"` and grab `matcher.group(1)` after `matcher.matches()` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/WGkTuM/1)).

Comment: Although Wiktor's regex is perfect and precisely covers the cases matching your data but in simplicity terms if you really want to capture everything before first D and at least one D is always present in your string, you can use this simple regex (.*?)D.* and capture group 1

Comment: So, what are your current results?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Thanks to you too!

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^(.*)D\d+S\d+\.[^.]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WGkTuM/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `D\d+` - `D` and 1 or more digits
- `S\d+` - `S` and 1 or more digits
- `\.` -  a dot
- `[^.]*` - 0+ chars other than `.`
- `$` - end of string.

This is how you may use it in your code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)D\\d+S\\d+\\.[^.]*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);

if(matcher.matches()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in regex but I have used the below code that I found online, to extract the name and the extension from a full file name:

```
String fullName = "2018.annualD01S02.pdf";
String name = fullName.split("\\.(?=[^\\.]+$)")[0];
System.out.println(name);
```

prints

```
2018.annualD01S02
```

the 2nd item of the split is the extension